# How to synthesize user voice into string by nsspeechsynthesizer in ios7

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, synthesizer

I would to convert user voice to a string by using nsspeechsynthesizer or other ios7 way. I can only find a way to do the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`NSSpeechSynthesizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsspeechsynthesizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class only exists on OS X.

iOS 7 introduced [`AVSpeechSynthesizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) and related classes. But as the name suggests, these are for *synthesizing* speech — text to speech — not recognizing it (speech to text).

iOS provides no system API for the latter, but there are several third party speech recognition systems available that you could search for.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer but i was not able to find one. Can you show me some possible free?

Comment: [A quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+speech+recognition) reveals several speech recognition toolkits for iOS, some of which appear to be free.